How to open 1 submenu and close others
My parent dropdowns are working perfectly. Like 1 open and when i click on 2nd the first one closes. But this is not working for submenus. All Submenu can be opened at once. But 1 want 1 sub menu at a time to be opened


<script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        // Function to handle dropdown toggles

function handleDropdownToggle(toggle) {

    toggle.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior

        var dropdownMenu = toggle.nextElementSibling;



        // Toggle visibility of the dropdown menu

        dropdownMenu.classList.toggle('show');



        // Find the parent <li> with class .has-dropdown and add/remove the active class

        var parentLi = toggle.closest('li.has-dropdown');

        if (parentLi) {

            if (dropdownMenu.classList.contains('show')) {

                parentLi.classList.add('active-dropdown');

                parentLi.classList.remove('closed-dropdown');

            } else {

                parentLi.classList.remove('active-dropdown');

                parentLi.classList.add('closed-dropdown');

            }

        }



        // Close other dropdown menus

        var otherDropdownMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu.show');

        otherDropdownMenus.forEach(function (menu) {

            if (menu !== dropdownMenu) {

                menu.classList.remove('show');



                // Also remove the active class and add the closed class from other parent <li> elements

                var otherParentLi = menu.closest('li.has-dropdown');

                if (otherParentLi) {

                    otherParentLi.classList.remove('active-dropdown');

                    otherParentLi.classList.add('closed-dropdown');

                }

            }

        });

    });

}



// Assuming you want to attach this to multiple toggles, you might do something like this:

document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle').forEach(function(toggle) {

    handleDropdownToggle(toggle);

});





        // Get all dropdown toggles

        var dropdownToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.has-dropdown > .nav-link');



        // Add click event listener to each dropdown toggle

        dropdownToggles.forEach(handleDropdownToggle);



        // Get all submenu toggles

        var submenuToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item > .nav-link');

        // Add click event listener to each dropdown toggle



        // Add click event listener to each submenu toggle

        submenuToggles.forEach(function (toggle) {

            toggle.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

                var dropdownMenu = toggle.closest('.dropdown-menu');

                dropdownMenu.classList.add('show');



                // Close other dropdown menus

                var otherDropdownMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu.show');

                otherDropdownMenus.forEach(function (menu) {

                    if (menu !== dropdownMenu) {

                        menu.classList.remove('show');

                    }

                });



                // Prevent event propagation to parent dropdown

                event.stopPropagation();

            });

        });

    });





</script>

I added a code above. I tried many thing from chatgpt but nothing work.
I am trying from past 5 hours but nothing works as I want.

https://frosthubusa.com/ here you can see. Main dropdown is fine but submenu are not

Can you include a [mre] of the current situation?

It would be hard to suggest anything without having the html structure or without having a minimal reproducible example.

Yes I solved it with jQuery. Thanks to all of you.
